# Is wind force for particle system linear or exponential?

Tags: graphics, physics, particles, particle-system

---

Hi gang!

I am developing a simple particle system mainly for learning purposes and I was wondering if a wind force is considered linear or exponential.

For example, would you implement it as linear:

```
Posx = posx + windx * time;
```

Or exponential:

```
Posx = posx + windx * time * time;
```

Let me add that I know a correct wind force takes other items into account such as mass, and more. But right now I am looking at it as a simple equation.

The reason I’m asking is because I’ve seen many particle systems implement it as a linear force but when I think of an aerosol can spraying in the wind, the particles seem to first shoot out in a particular direction before slowly being exponentially impacted by the wind force. It also doesn’t look very natural as a constant linear force.

Finally, I guess if it is exponential, it should have a maximum speed limit so that it doesn’t accelerate indefinitely, correct?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Suggestions are a bad thing to go to Stackoverflow looking for. Stackoverflow deals in answers.

Comment: Your second equation `Posx = posx + windx * time * time;` is not exponential but quadratic. The effect on particle velocity is "exponential" in the sense that it converges asymptotically to the wind velocity, assuming the force on the particle is directly proportional to its velocity *relative* to the wind.

Comment: Drag forces are usually linear with respect to the velocity in a low velocity regime. For velocities greater than those, the force is quadratic, see: [Drag forces][1].


  [1]: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-physics/chapter/5-2-drag-forces/